# If Y is positive then show that $\{Y=+\infty\} \subset \{E[Y\mid \mathcal{G}]=+\infty\}$(Almost surely for all $\omega \in \Omega$)

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

If Y is positive then show that $\{Y=+\infty\} \subset \{E[Y\mid \mathcal{G}]=+\infty\}$ where $Y$ ,lives on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and $\mathcal{G}\subseteq \mathcal{F}$.()

My attempt
In order to show $A \subset B$. Its enough to show $B^c \subseteq A^c$ i.e 
$$
 \{E[Y\mid \mathcal{G}]<+\infty\} \subseteq \{Y<+\infty\}  
$$

I set $A=\{E[Y\mid \mathcal{G}]<+\infty\}$ and clearly $A$ is $\mathcal{G}$ and hence $\mathcal{F}$-measurable .

If $A$ is not in $\{Y<+\infty\} $ almost surely then $A \cap \{Y=+\infty\}$ has a measure stricly greater than zero(assuming both $A$ and $\{Y=+\infty\}$ both have a strictly positive measure)

But on the set $\{Y=\infty\}$ we must have  $E[Y\mid \mathcal{G}]=\infty$ i.e $1_{\{Y=\infty\}}E[Y\mid \mathcal{G}]=+\infty$ a.s.

In other words the set $A \cap\{Y=+\infty \}$ is null

And hence $P(A \cap \{Y=+\infty\})=0$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: How do you define the conditional expectation of a random variable that is not integrable?

Comment: maybe like this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725323/random-variable-with-infinite-expectation-but-finite-conditional-expectation

Comment: They are not answering my question, but rather another ones and they also missed how to define a conditional expectation of a random variable that is not integrable. As far as I have read, no one does that.

Comment: @WillM. Actually I do not have an answer to your question. This question was posed in probability essentials by Jean jacod and Phillip protter and in the book they only define conditional expectation for integrable $Y$. Doesn’t the question refer to a random variable taking values in $[1,\infty]$ with mean infinity and conditioning it with respect to a random variable and the sigma algebra it generates  serve as $\mathcal{G}$

Comment: It is just that I was trying to write up a "solution" and found out myself in lots of trouble because $\{Y = \infty\}$ need not be in $\mathscr{G},$ however, the expected value of $E(Y \mid \mathscr{G})$ will be infinity on any $\mathscr{G}$-set containing $\{Y = \infty\}$ which does not prove it is infinity but I believe nothing more can be deduced.

Comment: @WillM. But does what I wrote make no sense ?

Comment: It is also not clear that $E(Y \mid \mathscr{G})$ _can possibly_ exist as its existence usually is proved by mean of the Radon-Nikodym derivative but this need sigma-finiteness of $A \mapsto \int_A Y dP$ for $A$ in $\mathscr{G},$ and this measure is not sigma finite.

Comment: I believe what you wrote here: "But on the set $\{Y=\infty\}$ we must have $E(Y \mid \mathcal{G}) = \infty$..." is exactly what you need to prove, that is to say, the argument you used is circular.

Comment: I see . I wonder if the other proof using hilbert spaces might allow for a conditional expectation with non integrable $Y$. I am going to check the proof now !

Comment: I am going to think a bit more about it . It looks deceptively easy !

Comment: On rereading my proof seems to make little sense